# How to read file on Linux server from Windows?

Tags: python, server, filepath

I'm running 3D simulations and storing the results on the external Linux server. Currently, to read the files I copy them and read them locally from my Win computer. 
It works fine if I use path below to access the file (they are in the folder specified below):

```
STAG_DIR = '\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\sun-simulations\\sun'
```

However, I want to access files directly from the server. I have tried the following path to the folder where I store simulation results:

```
STAG_DIR = '\\\\my_hostname\\short\\y89\\ms5128\\msun\\240x240x240\\By0=0.100\\2018_Aug_07'
```

I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\my_hostname\short\y89\ms5128\msun\240x240x240\By0=0.100\2018_Aug_07\msun01_00001.dat'

I made sure that the file `'sun01_00001.dat'` is in that folder.

A possible source of error might be that I require to login to the server before I can access the files.

Is there any way to access files from the server via Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a SFTP client to read the files. You cant directly replace the path with hostname. You should try something like [paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html) for file ready.

A quick sample:

```
client= ssh_client.open_sftp()
file = sftp_client.open('your_filename')
try:
    for line in file:
       #Do whatever you want for each line in the file     
finally:
    file.close()
```